# When I define a datasource ,what's the different between server.xml datesource and application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, jndi, websphere-liberty

My application runs on liberty application server, using springboot .And I define a datasource in server.xml file , and also I define the datasource in application.properties.
What's the different between the two file?

Comment: The one in `server.xml` is managed by tomcat and can be shared amongst applications, the one from `application.properties` is managed by the Spring container and cannot be shared.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But which one is efficient when the app is running @M.Deinum

Comment: Efficient? I suspect you mean active or used.. The one from the `application.properties` unless you specified a JNDI name for the datasource in there (then it will use the one from the `server.xml`).

Comment: Acctually, if I specified the JNDI name (like spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/dsname) in application.properties, it wiil "link to"  the datasource from server.xml  ?    @M.Deinum

Comment: Yes that is the whole point of doing it like that.

Comment: If you will use the one from `server.xml`, you can get rid of obolete springboot jars required for connection pooling (e.g. Hikari, etc), which will make your app smaller, and also better integrated with Liberty. In your props in that case you will just need jndi name.